# Write the result of an InputBox on a Cell if another Cell is = TRUE

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I want the below code to write the result of an `InputBox` on the cell L14 if the cell C4 has the text "TRUE".

```
    Sub dele()

    myValue4 = InputBox("What's the number?")

    If Range("C4").Value = "TRUE" Then
    Range("L14").Value = myValue4

    End If
```

Doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text conditions are case sensitive. Therefore try with this:

```
If Ucase(Range("C4").Value) = "TRUE" Then
```

However, if you have just a boolean value in Range("C4") this should also work:

```
If Range("C4").Value = True Then
```